# Printing a 'set' using standard set notation

Tags: python, recursion, printing, set

I have to print a set using standard set notation. I'm supposed to use recursion and there has to be a base case somewhere. the final answer should come out as a set, and I must print without adding a new line.

this is a function that is supposed to print out a powerset of random integers. the first function builds the random integers and the second function builds the powerset while the last function prints the set. I have the first two functions as well as the last, but when I run the code, it sometimes prints a set and other times comes up empty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

The whole things begins like this:

```
from random import *

def randomSet (n, up):
    return sample(range(up), n)


def powerset (A):
    if A == []:
        return [[]]
    aoba = A[0]
    imax = powerset(A[1:])
    doggo = []
    for set in imax:
        doggo.append([aoba] + set)
    return doggo + imax


def printSet (A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if i in A:
          print ((set(A)),end="")
```

There is a tester function that I didn't put here, but the point is that my code will not work right all the time. Sometimes it runs like this:

```
The powerset of 
{0, 38, 58, 30, 24}
is 
#supposed to show the powerset of the set above but it is always blank
```

and other times it runs like this:

```
The powerset of 
#nothing....just nothing!!!
is 
#never anything here
```

Comment: Huh, can you describe what your `printSet` function is suppposed to do exactly? Because I try to understand your logic but this function just seems to be a perfect nonsense

Comment: Printing a set `A` is Python is simply done with `print(A)`

Comment: @LouisSugy i edited the question, does it make more sense?

Comment: How do you call those functions? In the "nothing" case, maybe `n` is `0`?

Answer (score 1):

Your print function doesn't work.  Change it to print(set(A)) and you'll be golden.  Here's a breakdown why it doesn't work:

```
def printSet (A):

    # range(len(A)) produces a list of the range of values [0,1,2,3,... len(A)]
    # and then iterates over it, so I starts at 0 in the loop, then goes
    # to 1, then 2, etc.
    for i in range(len(A)):

        # so here, you are checking if 0 is in your set on the first iteration
        # then 1, then 2 etc  and you print out the values of it is.
        if i in A:
            print ((set(A)),end="")
```

so your function fails when there isn't a number in the set that is in the range from zero to the length of your set

for example {32, 24, 10} will never print, because none of the values are equal to 0, 1, or 2 (which are the values in the list created by range(set(A)) in this example)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18968851)

Comment: @Satendra I modified my post to add a detailed response to the post.  I didn't have enough reputation to comment on the post, so I originally made an "Answer" requesting more info from the OP with the intent of modifying it to give a solution

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, you loop the `range` and then test whether those numbers are in the set, but that check does not make sense. Instead, you should just loop the elements and print them directly.

```
def printSet (A):
    for i in A:
        print(set(i), end="")
```

But this does not really print those in "standard set notation". For example, the surrounding `{...}` are missing, and the empty set will print as `set()`. Instead, you can use something like this:

```
def printSet (A):
    print("{" + ", ".join(str(set(i)) if i else "{}" for i in A) + "}")
```

Output for `printSet(powerset(randomSet(5, 10)))`:

```
{{8, 9, 5, 6, 0}, {8, 9, 5, 6}, {8, 9, 5, 0}, {8, 9, 5}, {8, 0, 5, 6}, {8, 5, 6}, {8, 0, 5}, {8, 5}, {8, 9, 6, 0}, {8, 9, 6}, {8, 9, 0}, {8, 9}, {8, 0, 6}, {8, 6}, {8, 0}, {8}, {0, 9, 5, 6}, {9, 5, 6}, {0, 9, 5}, {9, 5}, {0, 5, 6}, {5, 6}, {0, 5}, {5}, {0, 9, 6}, {9, 6}, {0, 9}, {9}, {0, 6}, {6}, {0}, {}}
```

For more levels of nesting, you could make a recursive function. Note that this does not `print` but `return` the result, i.e. you'd have to do `print(tostr(...))`.

```
def tostr(A):
    if isinstance(A, (list, tuple, set, frozenset)):
        return "{" + ", ".join(map(tostr, A)) + "}"
    else:
        return str(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should try and improve your variable naming to be more descriptive. Don't use `set` as a variable name as it will remove Python's `set()` function.

The main problem is that if use Python's `set()`, an empty set would be shown as `set()` not `{}`.

You pass the function a list of lists. Each list contains numbers. The aim is to wrap each lists of numbers with `{}` and also the whole thing. So one approach would be to first convert each number into a string. The simplest way to do this is to use Python's `map()` function. This applies a function to each item in a list a returns the resulting list. In this case we can apply the `str` function which converts items into strings. So the result would be:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

With this you can use `join()` to create a single string:

```
', '.join(['1', '2', '3'])
```

would give you a string:

```
'1, 2, 3'
```

You then just need to wrap this with `{}`. Finally, the output powerset needs to be wrapped as well:

```
def printSet(A):
    print('{' + ', '.join('{' + ', '.join(map(str, a_set)) + '}' for a_set in A) + '}')

r = random_set(3, 50)
printSet(powerset(r))
```

This would display something like:

```
{{32, 41, 10}, {32, 41}, {32, 10}, {32}, {41, 10}, {41}, {10}, {}}
```